# NOT(!) in objective c

Tags: objective-c, operators

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=[secondSplitArrayValue count]; i++)   
{    
  if (![[secondSplitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"NULL"] ||  
  ![[splitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Error"]   
    {  
        [secondSplitArrayValue removeObjectAtIndex:i];  
    }  
}
```

I am trying to remove value of array at particular index where string is NOT EQUAL (!=) to NULL or Error. 
But in debugging time object is removed where NULL and Error present but I want to remove object where Null and Error not present.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably looking for this I think:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=[secondSplitArrayValue count]; i++)   
{    
  if (!([[secondSplitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"NULL"] ||  
  [[splitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Error"])   
    {  
        [secondSplitArrayValue removeObjectAtIndex:i];  
    }  
}
```

This way you inverse the boolean operation only after you have completed the check for both cases, and the OR operation of both of the resulting checks.

Comment: ok, that means instead to put !(NOT) in every || (OR) i have to put on whole condition,ok will try for this

Comment: BTW, `!(a || b)` == `!a && !b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=[secondSplitArrayValue count]; i++)   
{    
  if (([[secondSplitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"NULL"] == FALSE) ||  
  ([[splitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Error"] == FALSE))

    {  
        [secondSplitArrayValue removeObjectAtIndex:i];  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=[secondSplitArrayValue count]; i++)   
{    
  if (!([[secondSplitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"NULL"] ||  
  [[splitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Error"] ))  
    {  
        [secondSplitArrayValue removeObjectAtIndex:i];  
    }  
}
```

See if this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=[secondSplitArrayValue count]; i++)   
{    
  if (!([[secondSplitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"NULL"]) ||  
  !([[splitArrayValue objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Error"]))   
    {  
        [secondSplitArrayValue removeObjectAtIndex:i];  
    }  
}
```